# How can I pass TimeSpan.FromSeconds to a converter via the ConverterParameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters, func

Given the following :

```
namespace Foo.Converters {
    public class TimespanConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) =>
            ( parameter as Func<double, TimeSpan> )?.Invoke( ( double )( value ) );
        public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) =>
            throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }
}
```

How can I pass `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` to the `ConverterParameter`?

I've tried the following but it did not work -

```
<Window
    x:Class="Foo.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Foo.Converters"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <c:TimespanConverter x:Key="TSC" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding
            Seconds, Source={x:Static Application.Current},
            Converter={StaticResource TSC},
            ConverterParameter={x:Static lib:TimeSpan.FromSeconds}}" />
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

I get the error in designer - `The member "FromSeconds" is not recognized or is not accessible`. I've checked the TimeSpan struct and it is contained within the `System` namespace ( under the `mscorlib` assembly ), and I've used `.FromFOO` countless times for conversions in the past ( just not in this fashion ).

I do know that I could just call `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` directly in the converter, but I was hoping to have something more flexible.

So is what I'm trying to do possible? How can I do this correctly?

Comment: TimeSpan.FromSeconds is a method, and definitely *not* a func..  Just pass in a string that your converter will `switch` on and move on.

Comment: Tch. Okay. Not ideal, and definitely not what I was looking for but I suppose what would be a more eloquent workaround is to expose the `TimeSpan.FromFOO` methods as Funcs from within the converter itself and pass those as the converter parameter.

Comment: Well, *other Will*, you can always create that yourself. Create a static type that exposes properties that you can use in a Static binding that will work with your value converter...

Comment: Yeah, usually when I'm talking to myself, I'm the only one involved in the conversation. See edit.

Comment: I think you should post it as solution rather than edit given it ***is*** the solution and would be nice to have for records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLUTION

With thanks to a helpful commenter, the error was in the implementation. Evidently, you cannot implicitly pass method or function names as arguments ( at least, not in from XAML ).

To circumvent this, I have changed the converter code to expose the `TimeSpan.FromFOO` functions as `Func<double,TimeSpan>` properties so that they can be passed to the ConverterParameter -

```
namespace Foo.Converters {
    public class TimespanConverter : IValueConverter {
        public static Func<double, TimeSpan> FromMilliseconds => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds;
        public static Func<double, TimeSpan> FromSeconds => TimeSpan.FromSeconds;
        public static Func<double, TimeSpan> FromMinutes => TimeSpan.FromMinutes;
        public static Func<double, TimeSpan> FromHours => TimeSpan.FromHours;
        public static Func<double, TimeSpan> FromDays => TimeSpan.FromDays;

        public object Convert(
            object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) =>
            ( parameter as Func<double, TimeSpan> )?.Invoke( ( double )( value ) );
        public object ConvertBack(
            object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) =>
            throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }
}
```

And the window -

```
<Window
    x:Class="Foo.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Foo.Converters"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <c:TimespanConverter x:Key="TSC" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding
            Seconds, Source={x:Static Application.Current},
            Converter={StaticResource TSC},
            ConverterParameter={x:Static c:TimespanConverter.FromSeconds}}" />
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

The design-time error has gone away, but the text still doesn't show. I'm less worried about the text actually showing and the best method for implementing this, and this seems to be the best option for now. Additionally, it can be extended to any instance where one may wish to pass a Func as a ConverterParameter.

Comment: Application.Current doesn't have a property called Seconds which I would guess is why no text is showing. Check your output for a binding error. I'm not sure where you're expecting to get this Seconds value from, but it won't be there.

Comment: it does if i added the property. i didn't post that code because i was hoping some things would be implicit.